# Access Wireguard client from local network

Tags: routing, vpn, wireguard

I have a local network (192.168.0.X) and Wireguard server on 192.168.0.3 with Wireguard subnet (10.1.0.X).

When I'm connected to VPN, i have access to my local network. But when i want to get access to WG client from my local network, it doesn't work.

So how to get access to WG client from local network?